# How to repair this couch?

Tags: repair, furniture

I bought this leather (leatherette?) couch 1.5 years ago but recently noticed that the surface was damaged.  Please see the photo below.  How should I repair it?  Since I bought an "extended warranty" plan, I can try to give the company a call.

[image]

Comment: The company handling the "protection plan" declined to fix the problem -- they wrote that "based on the service technician’s report you have cracking/peeling on your furniture. According to the terms and conditions of your warranty cracking/peeling is not a covered issue."

I am not taking this lying down, because we paid $250 for the protection plan.

Answer (score 2):

There are vinyl patch kits available, most often sold for use repairing car seats. I've had mediocre success with them.

However, since you have that extended warranty, it's definitely worth checking if this is covered first; anything you do might be an excuse to void that warranty. I suspect thst this will be considered normal wear and not covered but ya never know until you ask.

Comment: I bought the couch from Macy's.  I looked up the specs online, where it says it's "a grade 3 Semi Aniline leather- top grain to touch and split on outside sides and back".  In theory the area shown in the photo (the seat) should be  covered with top-grain leather, but it looks like it's vinyl.  Hmm.